# How do I zoom in and out with Olympus Digital PEN series cameras?

Tags: zoom, olympus, manual-mode

There is a dial with a magnifier icon, but it doesn’t do the zooming. The lens doesn’t have zooming, it only has focus.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Olypmus Digital PEN series cameras are interchangeable lens cameras. The camera itself does not perform the zooming — you can zoom only if the lens attached to the camera is a zoom lens.

It sounds like the lens attached to your camera is a [*prime lens*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/what-is-the-definition-of-a-prime-lens). That is, it has only a single focal length, meaning it cannot zoom.

Comment: Most of them, including the E-P5 pictured, do include a "Digital Tele-converter" function that will produce a 2x "digital zoom" (aka center crop) on JPEG output. The image quality is reduced (like zooming on a phone) but if you find the function useful, you can map it to the "magnify" button in the settings. See page 70 of [the manual](http://www.olympusamerica.com/files/oima_cckb/E-P5_INSTR_MANUAL_EN.PDF) for details.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle true, but “digital tele-converter” or “digital zoom”, despite the name, is not zoom. It’s in-camera cropping (and possible interpolation), nothing more, nothing less.  For people used to compact fixed-lens cameras with “W / T” buttons, the distinction between zoom-as-lens-property (I.e., ILCs) vs zoom-as-camera-property can be unexpected.

Comment: Agreed, but it seemed like the information might be of interest to the OP.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle You could always write an answer and include that info.