# Can a lens be a zoom lens and a macro lens at the same time?

Tags: zoom, telephoto, macro-lenses

I am planning to buy an entry level SLR camera, mainly for use capturing macro and portrait photos. However, I'm a bit confused by [this lens](http://www.dpreview.com/products/tamron/lenses/tamron_70-300_4-5p6_di) which is described as "Tamron AF 70 - 300 mm F/4-5.6 Di LD Macro".

Correct me if I'm wrong, from the description I think it's a telephoto zoom lens because of the 70 - 300 mm range - but the title also says that it's a "Macro". Can a lens be zoom and macro at the same time?

Comment: Does [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/what-is-a-macro-lens) explain things enough for you? "Macro", "telephoto" and "zoom" are orthogonal concepts - a lens can be zero, one, two or all three of those.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipKendall. I understand the meaning of macro. My confusion still stands

Comment: Thanks @PhilipKendall for editing my question. This now looks cleaner. Will post another question for other doubts :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most consumer-grade variable aperture zoom lenses, this lens is a series of compromises carefully designed to do many jobs reasonably well. While, for example, it will take a very good photograph at 100mm, it will not have the same image quality from the center all the way to the corners as, say, a Zeiss Makro-Planar 100mm lens. However, it also doesn't cost US$1800 for a single focal length!

Likewise, this lens has a reasonable macro capability, meaning that it can make macro photographs at a reproduction ratio of 1:2, meaning that objects will be reproduced at 1/2 life size on a 35mm sensor or film. In comparison, most purpose-built Micro-Nikkor lenses can make photographs at a reproduction ratio of 1:1 or life-sized. For example:  http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/AF-S-VR-Micro-Nikkor-105mm-f%252F2.8G-IF-ED.html

As in all things in life, compromises are made as to cost, quality, weight, complexity, et al.

Comment: Thanks @chili555. You made me understand the meaning of the lens :)

Comment: Overall, it's not half bad at it either. It's not as sharp as a good Nikon, but neither does it have the colour aberration that my Nikon 24-120 has. Of the two, I use the Tamron daily, I'm selling the Nikon.

Answer (score 6):

Fairly simply, that lens is all three of:

- A [macro lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/what-is-a-macro-lens), as it can produce magnifications which approach 1:1.
- A [telephoto](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/telephoto/info) lens with a relatively long focal length and correspondingly small angle of view.
- A [zoom](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/zoom/info) lens with a variable focal length.

These are three orthogonal concepts - as with this lens, it's perfectly possible for a lens to be all three of these at once.

Comment: I'm a beginner.Thanks for being patient. So how do I define this lens "Tamron AF 70 - 300 mm F/4-5.6 Di LD Macro for Nikon Digital SLR Lens". Is it a variable focal length or a MACRO?

Comment: It is *both* variable focal length and macro.